# Compiling Java unit tests very slow

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, compilation, lombok

I'm working on a new multi module Maven project (Java11+) as we added more and more unit tests to our project I noticed that compiling our tests was getting really slow. So I started profiling the project and here are the results for compiling a typical module:

- "test-compile" took 109s for 18 files
- "compile" (non test classes) took 4s for 76 files.

I have run this on my Windows notebook with Java11 (OpenJDK) but can reproduce it in Java17 and OracleJDK and also on Linux machines. I have no idea what's causing this vast difference (0.05s per file vs. 6s per file). We are using mainly Spring-Boot and for our tests we use Junit5 with spring-boot-starter-test, Mockito and AssertJ.

Here is a minimal reproducer using our maven config:
https://github.com/elbird/slow-test-compile

Comment: Can you provide more information about your code or if it is possible link to your code?

Comment: Do you use things like lombok, mapstruct or alike? Also the full pom would be helpful...Are we really talking about the compile time or the run time for the test... full log file would help here...Also check if you have a antivirus app running ...

Comment: We use lombok and mapstruct. Unfortunatley since this is a private project for a customer I cannot share any real code. I can later on try to create project similiar to ours reproducing this issue and put somwhere public.

Comment: I added a reproducer using our maven config: https://github.com/elbird/slow-test-compile

Comment: Can you still share a bit more information on this? Maybe also how you are executing the tests? Lombok is "known" to cause issues with IDEs from time to time

Comment: It's not about executing the tests, this runs fine - it was compiling my test classes which was very slow. I'm using maven to compile everything (see link to my reproducer on GitHub) but could reproduce this issue also using just javac on the CLI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error I found the culprit: lombok.
I cannot explain why but in my reproducer https://github.com/elbird/slow-test-compile I found that lombok at least in version 1.18.20 (and lower) is really slow when compiling with Java11+. (especially with heavly overloaded methods like assertjs `assertThat()`)

Luckily with lombok 1.18.22 this issue seems to be fixed. The fix seems to be related to this Bug: https://github.com/projectlombok/lombok/issues/2652 which is fixed with the following changelog entry:

> IMPROBABLE BREAKING CHANGE: If the underlying compiler and --release / --source option is 10 or higher, lombok's val is now replaced by final var.

https://projectlombok.org/changelog

TLDR: update to lombok 1.18.22 fixed the issue.